# Tabular issue in my code

Tags: tables

I want to create a similar copy to the "Exercice 3" with some changes

[image]

What I've done until now:  [image]

And my code is_

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[default]{frcursive}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{ferrarired}{rgb}{1.0, 0.11, 0.0}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{ferrarired}{\textbf{{\large \\ Exercice 3 : } }}
    
         \begin{enumerate}[label=\color{ao} \textbf{ \arabic*) } ]
            \item Résoudre dans l'ensemble des nombres complexes $\mathbb{C}$ l'équation : $z^{2}-4z+29=0$
   
            \item  Dans le plan complexe rapporté à un repère orthonormé direct  $(O,\vec{e_{1}},\vec{e_{2}})$ , on considère les points $\Omega $ , $A$ et $B$ d'affixes respectives $\omega$ , $a$ et $b$ telles que $\omega =2+5i$ , $a=5+2i$ et $b=5+8i$
                \begin{enumerate}[label=\textcolor{ao(english)}{\textbf{\alph*-}}] 
                    \item Soit $u$ le nombre complexe tel que $u=b-\omega $ 
                    
                    Vérifier que $u=3+3i$ puis montrer que $\displaystyle{\arg u\equiv \frac{\pi}{4}\left[ 2\pi \right ]}$
                    \item Déterminer un argument du nombre complexe $\bar{u}$ ($\bar{u}$ étant le conjugué de $u$)
                    \item Vérifier que $\displaystyle{a-\omega =\bar{u}}$ puis en déduire que $\displaystyle{\Omega A=\Omega B}$ et que $\displaystyle{\arg \left ( \frac{b-\omega }{a-\omega } \right )\equiv \frac{\pi }{2}\left [ 2\pi  \right ]}$
                    \item On considère la rotation $R$ de centre $\Omega $ et d'angle $ \displaystyle{\frac{\pi }{2}}$. \\  Déterminer l'image du point $A$ par la rotation $R$.
                 \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**My problem is**:

I don't know how to make the lines and mark every question just like the first picture.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE: my humble suggestion use the button `{}` (sample code to fix the code as now). You have two `enumitem` in your code.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastiano for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is much better, though not exact information but for advise and observation.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the tabularx extension.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[default]{frcursive}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{ferrarired}{rgb}{1.0, 0.11, 0.0}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent


\begin{tabularx}{1.0\linewidth}{|l|X|}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textcolor{ferrarired}{\textbf{\large Exercice 3 : }}}\\
  \hline{}
.75&\begin{enumerate}[label=\color{ao} \textbf{ \arabic*) } ]%
\item Résoudre dans l'ensemble des nombres complexes $\mathbb{C}$ %
  l'équation : $z^{2}-4z+29=0$%
%
\item Dans le plan complexe rapporté à un repère orthonormé direct%
  $(O,\vec{e_{1}},\vec{e_{2}})$ , on considère les points $\Omega $ ,%
  $A$ et $B$ d'affixes respectives $\omega$ , $a$ et $b$ telles que %
  $\omega =2+5i$ , $a=5+2i$ et $b=5+8i$%
\end{enumerate}\\
.75&\begin{enumerate}[start=1,series=toto,label=\textcolor{ao(english)}{\textbf{\alph*-}}]%
  \item Soit $u$ le nombre complexe tel que $u=b-\omega $ %
%
    Vérifier que $u=3+3i$ puis montrer que %
    $\displaystyle{\arg u\equiv \frac{\pi}{4}\left[ 2\pi \right ]}$%
  \end{enumerate}\\
.25& \begin{enumerate}[resume=toto,label=\textcolor{ao(english)}{\textbf{\alph*-}}]%
  \item Déterminer un argument du nombre complexe $\bar{u}$ ($\bar{u}$ %
    étant le conjugué de $u$)%
  \end{enumerate}\\
 .75&\begin{enumerate}[resume=toto,label=\textcolor{ao(english)}{\textbf{\alph*-}}]%
  \item Vérifier que $\displaystyle{a-\omega =\bar{u}}$ puis en %
    déduire que $\displaystyle{\Omega A=\Omega B}$ et que %
    $\displaystyle{\arg \left ( \frac{b-\omega }{a-\omega } \right%
      )\equiv \frac{\pi }{2}\left [ 2\pi \right ]}$%
  \end{enumerate}\\
  .5&\begin{enumerate}[resume=toto,label=\textcolor{ao(english)}{\textbf{\alph*-}}]%
   \item On considère la rotation $R$ de centre $\Omega $ et d'angle %
     $ \displaystyle{\frac{\pi }{2}}$.

     Déterminer l'image du point %
     $A$ par la rotation $R$.%\\
   \end{enumerate}\\%
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: pb]

Comment: Thank youuuuuuu so much ..... it helps me soooo much

Answer (score 1):

An idea with the `exam` class :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[default]{frcursive}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{ferrarired}{rgb}{1.0, 0.11, 0.0}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\color{ao}\thequestion)}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{ferrarired}{\underline{\textbf{{\large \\ Exercice 3 (3 points)} }}}
\begin{questions}
    \question[0.75] Résoudre dans l'ensemble des nombres complexes $\mathbb{C}$ l'équation : $z^{2}-4z+29=0$
    
    \question Dans le plan complexe rapporté à un repère orthonormé direct  $(O,\vec{e_{1}},\vec{e_{2}})$ , on considère les points $\Omega $ , $A$ et $B$ d'affixes respectives $\omega$ , $a$ et $b$ telles que $\omega =2+5i$ , $a=5+2i$ et $b=5+8i$
    \begin{parts}
        
        \part[0.75] Soit $u$ le nombre complexe tel que $u=b-\omega $ 
        
        Vérifier que $u=3+3i$ puis montrer que $\displaystyle{\arg u\equiv \frac{\pi}{4}\left[ 2\pi \right ]}$
        
        \part[0.25] Déterminer un argument du nombre complexe $\bar{u}$ ($\bar{u}$ étant le conjugué de $u$)
        
        
        \part[0.75] Vérifier que $\displaystyle{a-\omega =\bar{u}}$ puis en déduire que \[\displaystyle{\Omega A=\Omega B}\] et que 
        
        \[\displaystyle{\arg \left ( \frac{b-\omega }{a-\omega } \right )\equiv \frac{\pi }{2}\left [ 2\pi  \right ]}\]
        
        \part[0.5] On considère la rotation $R$ de centre $\Omega $ et d'angle $ \displaystyle{\frac{\pi }{2}}$.
        
        Déterminer l'image du point $A$ par la rotation $R$.

        
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

And the output :

[image: MWE output]

Here you can find more info on using this class : https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Typesetting%20exams%20in%20LaTeX

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... but I really want it as a tabular.

Answer (score 1):

I have to remove the enumerate or itemize command, also the use of \newline [ or \ ] which works differently in LATEX. Hence, my suggested codes, and using three columns:

```
%\{Exercise Feby}
\documentclass[10pt, A4]{article} \usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} \\
 \usepackage[default]{frcursive}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{ferrarired}{gb}{1.0, 0.11, 0.0}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\title{Exercise February}
\author{Ibiloye Abiodun Christian}
\date{February 2021}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\textcolor{ferrarired}{\textbf{{\large Exercise 3 : } }} \\
\begin{tabular}{| c | l | c |}  
\hline 
{\bf W.pts} & {\centering {\bf Exercise 3} } & rmarks\\ 
\hline 
0.75 &  1. Résoudre dans l'ensemble des nombres complexes $\mathbb{C}$ l'équation : $z^{2}-4z+29=0$ & \\
   & 2. Dans le plan complexe rapporté à un repère orthonormé direct  $(O,\vec{e_{1}}, \vec{e_{2}})$ ,  on considère les points $\Omega $ , $A$ et $B$ d'affixes respectives $\omega$ , $a$ et $b$ telles que $\omega =2+5i$ , $a=5+2i$ et $b=5+8i$ & 10points \\
0.25 & \hspace{.3in} \bf{a.} Soit $u$ le nombre complexe tel que $u=b-\omega $. Vérifier que $u=3+3i$ puis montrer que $\displaystyle{\arg u\equiv \frac{\pi}{4}\left[ 2\pi \right ]}$ & \\
   & \hspace{.3in} \bf{b.} Déterminer un argument du nombre complexe $\bar{u}$ ($\bar{u}$ étant le conjugué de $u$) ? & \\
   & \hspace{.3in} \bf{c.} Vérifier que $\displaystyle{a-\omega =\bar{u}}$ puis en déduire que $\displaystyle{\Omega A=\Omega B}$ et que $\displaystyle{\arg \left ( \frac{b-\omega }{a-\omega } \right )\equiv \frac{\pi }{2}\left [ 2\pi  \right ]}$ ? & \\
   & \hspace{.3in} \bf{d.} On considère la rotation $R$ de centre $\Omega $ et d'angle $ \displaystyle{\frac{\pi }{2}}$ & 10 points  \\  
   0.75 & \hspace{.3in} \bf{e.} Déterminer l'image du point $A$ par la rotation $R$. & 5 points \\
   \hline 
   \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

A problem here is to wrap the overflowing text within column. Sorry, was feeling sleepy yesterday night. ! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anT84.png)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Using `tabularx` extension as given by @gigiair [ alternative could be `\begin{tabular}` and then `\vline` for the  margin .... `\end{tabular}`] has being very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should show us an MWE (Minimal Working example, a small but complete, compilable document, which can be tested as it is) with your suggestion for solution. I wonder, why someone should vrite `\vline` if the same effect (s)he can get with (shorter) `|` .

Comment: Alright, will try to do that and with |. Thanks @Zarko